# Chart.js: Some sectors not showing if difference is too big

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm passing the following config to [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html):

```
{
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [878, 19020, 100412286],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgb(255, 205, 86)'
      ],
      hoverOffset: 4
    }]
  }
}
```

But because of the huge difference between all three (given how much bigger `c` is), `c` ends up "overlapping" everything else and I just get a doughnut with only one color, showing only `c`.

If I try a smaller value for `c` all three sectors show up fine.

But I don't understand, **Chart.js** should've been able to show all pieces (set a minimum size for the smallest sector etc.)

Is there some parameter I can pass to the config to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logarithmic scale but only for lines. A donut is not a good choice for your use case

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/log.html

Config:

```
  const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Logarithmic'
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        display: true,
      },
      y: {
        display: true,
        type: 'logarithmic',
      }
    }
  },
};
```

Setup:

```
const DATA_COUNT = 7;
const NUMBER_CFG = {count: DATA_COUNT, min: 0, max: 100};

const labels = Utils.months({count: 7});
const data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: logNumbers(DATA_COUNT),
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      fill: false,
    },
  ]
};
```

Action

```
const logNumbers = (num) => {
  const data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
    data.push(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10.0) * Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)));
  }

  return data;
};

const actions = [
  {
    name: 'Randomize',
    handler(chart) {
      chart.data.datasets.forEach(dataset => {
        dataset.data = logNumbers(chart.data.labels.length);
      });
      chart.update();
    }
  },
];
```

Comment: This solution seems  a bit too much for such a small issue or at least for something that should've been the default UX behaviour anyway: *If a = 0 , b = 23908 and c = 200000000 I think I should still be able to clearly see 3 slices on the my doughnut chart*. A doughnut is a requirement I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is using 3 datasets, one for each data.

```
labels: ['a', 'b', 'c'],   
datasets: [
  {
    label: "My First Dataset",
    data: [878,0,0],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
      "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      "rgb(54, 162, 235)",          
    ],        
    offset:0,
    hoverOffset: 0,               
  },
  {
    label: "My First Dataset2",
    data: [0,19020,0],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
      "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
      "rgb(54, 162, 235)",          
    ],        
    offset:0,
    hoverOffset: 0,       

  },
  {
    label: "My First Dataset2",
    data: [0,0,100412286],
    backgroundColor: [
      "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
      "rgb(255, 99, 132)", 
      "rgb(54, 162, 235)",         
    ],        
    offset:0,
    hoverOffset: 0,       

  },
],
```

[image]

I hope this help.